# Papersize problem with Latex Article Class

Tags: pdf, latex, miktex

I'm new to Latex so hopefully this is just a simple problem.  I'm using MikTex on Windows.

My problem is that even though I specify the 'letterpaper' option in my class declaration (i.e., \documentclass[letterpaper]{article}), the pdf or dvi's that get created are set to use A4 paper.  That is, I check the paper size of the pdf and its shows 8.26x11.69 rather than 8.5x11.

Latex does seem to format differently depending on whether I specify the letterpaper or A4paper option.  That is, when I use the letterpaper option the resulting pdf has fewer lines per page than when I specify A4.  However either way the PDF's paper size is A4, even when formatting was for letter.

The result is that I can't get a good idea of the actual letterpaper layout from viewing the pdf, since it's always displayed on A4 paper.  I can print the A4 pdf to letter paper to get (I think) the correct hard copy output, but that's not really a solution.

Does anyone know what's wrong here or how I can fix it?

Comment: Now I am happy to see this. :-D In the whole world we struggle to get A4 paper format to work with LaTeX (on my install, without any option, the article class produces a useless letter format), and, for once, in the US you struggle to get Letter format working. By the way, a good solution would be to use A4 paper! ;-) cheers!

Comment: Do you have a solution, but I'm wondering what happen if you don't declare the paper size, because letter size is the default in LaTeX. I use MiKTeX too, without declare the paper size in the preamble, and I realized it has A4 as default (Settings of MiKTeX, in the general tab. Perhaps if you change it you will not need the geometry package), but in all my compilations I get documents in letter paper :) (Sorry for my English.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the paper size via the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/) package. Since you're already passing `letterpaper` to the article class, something like this should be enough:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
```

The more explicit way would be `\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}`.

If you typeset documents of this size more often than on A4 paper, you could change the global setting of the distribution. On TeXlive that would be done by invoking `tlmgr paper a4` in a terminal, but I don't know how that maps to MikTeX.

Comment: Thanks very much for your fast and accurate answer!  I was just coming back to StackOverflow to post the answer to my own question, but you beat me to it.  I discovered this is a common problem, here's one page describing problem and solution at the MikTex site:  http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=papergeom

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/papersize.pdf , A useful link that I followed and it worked. The problem in my case was I was using dvi->ps->pdf for compilation.

$dvips -tletter filename.dvi
$ps2pdf filename.ps filename.pdf

This solves the problem for me...